# Add tab view android

Tags: java, android, tabs

I have made a simple contact apps and now I wish to add tab view to this app. I am following the tutorial [here](http://androidexample.com/Tab_Layout_|_TabBar_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=103&aaid=125). Below is part of the source code for my MainActivity.jave:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ListView contactListView;
    private CursorAdapter contactListViewAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        contactListView = getListView(); // get ListView id
        contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewContactListListener);

        String[] from = new String[] { "familyName" }; // built an String array
                                                        // named "from"
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.contactTextView };
        contactListViewAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.contact_list_item, null, from, to);
        setListAdapter(contactListViewAdapter); // set adapter
    }
```

I tried to change "public class MainActivity extends ListActivity" to "public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{". However, I get the error "The method getListView() is undefined for the type MainActivity" and other similar errors. I need suggestions on how to fix this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListActivity` provides some help methods to manage `ListView` so if you want to change your parent activity from `ListActivity` to `TabActivity` you need to handle `ListActivity` behaviour yourself.
Basically you need to get and store somewhere the `ListView` object. Something like `mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list)` on your `onCreate` method and then implement missing method

```
ListView getListView()
{
    return mListView;
}
```

Also setting your adapter will be a bit different. Instead of calling  `setListAdapter(contactListViewAdapter); // set adapter` there should be `contactListView.setAdapter(contactListViewAdapter);`